# Iterate over groups and output those groups which met .loc conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

1. I'm trying to iterate over groups ( groupedby `AC No`)
2. The groups that meets the given condition (having 12 rows) as output.
   `data.loc[(data['Position'] <= 3) & (data['Votes %'] > 10.0) ].shape[0]) == 12`
   are assigned a dummy output as 1.

Let's start fresh and simple
I have stored my new filtered dataset as

```
q5_data = data.loc[(data['Position'] <= 3) & (data['Votes %'] > 10.0)]
print(q5_data.head(10))
```

Filtered dataset

```
   Election Year  Position                     Name  Votes  Votes %  \
0     2010-01-01         1             Rajesh Singh  42289     29.4   
1     2010-01-01         2    Mukesh Kumar Kushwaha  27618     19.2   
2     2010-01-01         3  Dheerendra Pratap Singh  20886     14.5   
14    2010-01-01         1          Bhagirathi Devi  51993     41.5   
15    2010-01-01         2               Naresh Ram  22211     17.7   
16    2010-01-01         3             Subodh Kumar  20095     16.0   
31    2010-01-01         1     Satish Chandra Dubey  45022     38.1   
32    2010-01-01         2        Alok Prasad Verma  24794     21.0   
33    2010-01-01         3          Fakhruddin Khan  22381     18.9   
46    2010-01-01         1     Prabhat Ranjan Singh  67510     50.4   

                         Party        AC name  AC No  
0          Janata Dal (United)  Valmiki Nagar      1  
1         Rashtriya Janata Dal  Valmiki Nagar      1  
2          Bahujan Samaj Party  Valmiki Nagar      1  
14       Bharatiya Janta Party       Ramnagar      2  
15    Indian National Congress       Ramnagar      2  
16  Nationalist Congress Party       Ramnagar      2  
31       Bharatiya Janta Party   Narkatiaganj      3  
32    Indian National Congress   Narkatiaganj      3  
33                 Independent   Narkatiaganj      3  
46         Janata Dal (United)         Bagaha      4
```

In above dataset I want to output only those groups or `AC Name` which have total count of 12.

Comment: some problem with solution?

Comment: If test `data['count'] = data.assign(test = m).groupby('AC No')['test'].transform('sum')` it get `12` ? So then correct assign `data.loc[data.assign(test = m).groupby('AC No')['test'].transform('sum') == 12, 'd1'] = 1` ?

Comment: Hi jezreal, thanks for the framework. After applying the `m` condition I should only get first 3 positions from every group( ``` AC No```) and for every election year (i.e. 4 ) and then check if those all those rows have values of VOTES % column > 10.0. Then count should sum up to 12. By applying your solution I still get AC No. within top 3 positions with VOTES% less than 10.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I have 4 election years. So 3 Positions * 4 years = 12 count

Comment: Here is main question need count matched rows by `m` if `True`s ? Or need something else? Data cannot be copied, hard to test...

Comment: I have added the solution  I am getting above. can you take a look

Comment: yes, it means per groups is 9 times Trues, 9 rows matched. And you need assign 1 to first 3 rows per groups matched mask `m` ?

Comment: Or need filter rows by `m` ? `print (df[m])` ?

Comment: But my second condition of Votes % > 10 is not met above after masking and then looking at that particular group AC No.

Comment: Can you explain how do you think working `data.assign(test = m).groupby('AC No')['test'].transform('sum')` ? seems expected something different like it working.

Comment: I have idea. Can you create some small data sample - 10 rows, 3 groups and explian what is expected ouput from this sample? Then solution apply to real data.

Comment: Reproducing my data would be hard. Can I share it somehow? I know it's not desirable.

Comment: Can you post first 10 rows like text?

Comment: I just manually change your data with remove some not necessary columns for count. Can you add expected ouput from this data? If necessary be free modify them.

Comment: Hi, do you understand how my conditions are formed now according to the ask of question mentioned above?

Comment: @condition is same, `(data['Position'] <= 3) & (data['Votes %'] > 10.0) `, but instead `12` compare by `3` or by `2`. Then please add expected ouput.

Comment: answer was change, I guess you need assign 1 to index 7, 8 if compare by `count=2`. Is it what need? Or something else?

Comment: Hi , i have  converted the problem into simpler terms . Can you now show how can I get this now

Comment: Still waiting how looks expected dataframe, can you add to question? I think if use only data from question what is final dataframe? datframe with some rows only? Or dataframe with new column like in my answer? Or something else?

Comment: I don't need  to output a dataframe. I need a list of groups/AC No that satisfies frequency counts=12

Comment: answer was edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243277/discussion-between-yash-agarwal-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count matched values by mask by [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) and then filter:

```
m = (data['Position'] <= 3) & (data['Votes %'] > 10.0) 
s = data.assign(test = m).groupby('AC No')['test'].sum()

out = s.index[s == 12].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for keeping up with my amateur-ship. I'll try to understand and learn more about mask and transform functions. Could you recommend any source

Comment: Your previous solution also worked.